# EK205 transit visa requirement for Milan Italy for Indian passport holder with US visa

Tags: schengen-visas, transit-visas, emirates

Can I book the EK 205 emirates flight that flys from Dubai to Milan and then Milan to JFK new york (same flight number) if I have indian passport and valid US visa?

I am getting mixed answers from different sources. I called the airline and they said there is no need of any visa for Milan but some other source over here https://www.musafirservices.com/emirates-airlines-update-travel-guidlies-for-us-travellers-from-india/ mentions that EK 205 is only for US nationals.

I don't want to blindly trust the airlines as I heard about similar instances where airlines said it should be fine but it wasn't (in terms of visa requirements).

Comment: The limitation you are referring to is under "Travel to Usa up to 00:01 EST on 8 November (2021)". We are now way after November 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Emirates visa check tool](https://www.emirates.com/fr/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=in&destination=us&transit=it), which is based on Timatic, the database used by all airlines to know documentation requirements tells us in your situation:

> ## Transit Countries
>
> ### Italy
>
> #### Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> #### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> (…)
>
> Passengers transiting through Milan (MXP) and arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 48 hours to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.
> - TWOV does not apply when transiting between terminals 1 and 2.

So, no, you don’t need a visa.

Note that the page you linked to is about Covid restrictions at the time, which have been lifted since then.

Comment: Thank you very much.